# I'm using bootstrap and the columns inside my container-fluid are stacking vertically and not stretching to fill all space horizontally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm following along with this video by 'thenewboston' https://youtu.be/c5xVxSFoyQw?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBPw1sFodruZUPheWVKchlM

My code isn't responding the same as in the video though and I cannot figure out why. I'm working through thenewboston bootstrap playlist and I can't believe I'm stuck on the 2nd video.

Here's a link to my code in GitHub https://github.com/Osyris93/BootstrapProject if you'd like to continue to help me or just follow me as I work through this playlist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>The bootstrap project</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">    </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous">    </script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous">    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid>
<h1>3 column layout</h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: #FF9999">Left</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: #99CCFF">Middle</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: #00CC99">Right</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! The issue you're seeing is because of the missing end quote after your container class. To fix, simple switch:

```
<div class="container-fluid>
```

To this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Typos are a common part of development and I've always found that using tools that have context highlighting can save you hours of frustration over one missing character.